# Eclipse for Visual Studio dummies

Tags: eclipse

Looking for links to good information for Eclipse beginners.   I've been a c# developer for sometime and I feel like I'm swimming in molasses.  I'm especially interested in anything like the snippets functionality and how to use it (for example the prop snippet to create a property)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you start with the tutorials on the "Welcome" screen (automatically shown on first launch, or via Help menu).

After that, a lot of stuff can be discovered by poking around. The built-in help is also quite good, and failing that, just google for it.

Set yourself some goal, and do a bit of research; I've found most stuff fairly easily that way.

As for snippets: I'm not terribly familiar with VS, but I gather they are basically code templates that you can insert and then fill in.

In Eclipse, that would be auto-complete (or "Content Assist"), triggered by Ctrl-Space. Just try it, it's fairly clever. It will offer completions of variable names, functions etc., but will also offer common snippets like creating constructors, public methods etc. E.g. type "public ctrl-spc", and it should offer a template for a public method (try ctrl-space several times to cycle through proposals).

You can also create your own auto-complete code snippets. These are called templates in Eclipse, to be found in the prefs under "Java / Editor / Templatest".  Templates can be triggerd in auto-complete by typing the (beginning) of the template's name, then auto-completing.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I was also a VS user for a long time and found Eclipse confusing, requires a lot more configuration to get it up and running first off.

Found this very helpful post on a Google search
http://benpryor.com/blog/2006/03/03/top-10-tips-for-new-eclipse-users/
.

I don't use it often but here are a few things that threw me at first.

Workspaces confused me, there is no exact equivalent in VS, I'd say they are a bit like Solutions. I made the mistake of keeping all my projects in one workspace and after a year of work Eclipse could barely open the workspace.

You don't need to hit 'Build' to compile your code, it keeps compiling in the background so there is always an up to date list of bugs, called problems in Eclipse.

When you run your code in debug all the windows jump about some disappear and lots of strange new ones open. These different layouts are called perspectives. There is a tab bar next to the main tool bar which lets you move between open perspectives or you can close them using the Window menu.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the very good Eclipse tutorials and documentation sleske mentioned here are some other good tutorials and introductions:

- [IBM tutorial for Visual Studio users](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/os-dw-os-eclipsevs-i.html) - you have to register for reading this tutorial but registration is free and you can download a bunch of really good Eclipse materials
- [Effective Eclipse - Custom Templates](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ) - this article shows you Eclipse's "snippets funcionality" in details